# Make work REPLACE INTO with specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column `ID Auto-increment` and `SKU` with `UNIQUE` index and some more columns.

ID is just a counter and SKU is the unique property for each row.

Instead of checking a record with `SELECT` query if it exists and then updating, I want to do it with `REPLACE INTO` to work with `SKU` column.

I know `REPLACE INTO` behavior that it deleted the previous row and inserts the new one.

But currently it is working with `ID` column.

Can I specifically make `REPLACE INTO` work with `SKU` column?

Answer (score -1):

Don't specify the ID column in your statement, only specify the SKU column. Since it is a `UNIQUE` index, the `REPLACE INTO` should take it into account. The `ID` column is auto-increment, if you leave it empty it should be auto-generated by the DB.

Comment: what are u saying? :( U didnt understand my question

Comment: Yes I did understand your question. Read my response again instead of downvoting it.